# Ui-view within ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i've an application that has multiple modules and it's using ui-view to switch between those modules.
My idea is to have within these parent $stateProvider, another $stateProvider inside each of these modules, so it can navigate inside those modules without the page reloading.

The outer $stateProvider is:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('core',{
                url: '/core'
            })
            .state('thing', {
                url: '/core/thing',
                templateUrl: './modules/thing/views/base.html'
            })
            .state('people',{
                url: '/core/people',
                templateUrl: './modules/people/views/list.html'
            })
    })
```

This is an example, but this system could scale a lot. And i want to use $stateProvider inside the module that is responsible for people state, for example. And inside the module 'app.people', using this config:

```
 $stateProvider
            .when('list',{
                url: 'list/',
                templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
                controller: 'ListController',
                controllerAs: 'list'
            })
            .when('insert',{
                url: 'insert/',
                templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
                controller: 'FormController',
                controllerAs: 'form'
            })
            .when('edit',{
                url: 'edit/:id',
                templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
                controller: 'FormController',
                controllerAs: 'form',
                resolve: {
                    entity: ['EntityService', '$stateParams', function (EntityService, $stateParams) {
                        return EntityService.load($stateParams.id);
                    }]
                }
            })
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda easy to do that. Sorry about the question, but you just have to do this:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('thing.list', {
                url: '/list',
                templateUrl: './modules/thing/views/list.html',
                controller: 'ListController',
                controllerAs: 'list'
            })
            .state('thing.insert', {
                url: '/insert',
                templateUrl: './modules/thing/views/form.html',
                controller: 'FormController',
                controllerAs: 'form'
            })
            .state('thing.edit', {
                url: '/edit/:id',
                templateUrl: './modules/thing/views/form.html',
                controller: 'FormController',
                controllerAs: 'form'
            })
```

in the module that is on the inside.